# Any good tutorials on creating blackberry web and native applications?

Tags: blackberry

The tutorials for creating blackberry applications seem to be severely limited. Even on the blackberry site the samples aren't very good.  I want to learn about building a user interface with form objects like text boxes, drop downs, and buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defiantly recommend RIM's Blackberry developer resource. Some really solid documentation on both topics.

**Java Development** 
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/learningresources/

**Web Development** 
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/learningresources.jsp

For both links review the Knowledge base and Reference Docs. I would like to add more direct links, but RIM's site has a lot of cruddy user instance specific URL's (hence the edit).

Comment: both these link get 404 errors and don't exist.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=13264

Answer (score -3):

Video based tutorial on BlackBerry 10 app development: http://udemy.com/blackberry-10-app-development